# Java send data to class where object was initialized

Tags: java, class

We have simple initialization:
Example:

```
Class1
{
  public Class1
  {
   Class2 object = new Class2();
  }

   public SomeMethod(String anyString)
    {...}
}
```

So what is the best way to call SomeMethod in Class1 from Class2 and pass "anyString" value?
Now I'm using custom events and interface.
But maybe there is better, more rational way to do this?

Comment: What is public Class1 fragment. Is that a constructor with missed paranthese?

Comment: First of all, your example isn't legal Java, but that aside, it's still not clear what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "pass 'anyString' value"? What do you want to pass that to/from? Do you just need to know how to call a method in one class from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But maybe there is better, more rational way to do this?

Yep.

```
Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Class2 object = new Class2(this);
    }

   public SomeMethod(String anyString)
   {...}
}

Class2
{
    public Class2(Class1 parent)
    {
         parent.SomeMethod("A String value");
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

Simply pass an instance of the parent object into the child class. The child class can call the desired method directly.

**Java Naming Conventions**

The convention states that methods start with a lower case letter.

```
SomeMethod -> someMethod
```

Comment: exactly what I was typing out. +1

Comment: Publishing `this` from within the constructor is a bad idea because the reference is assigned before the object is fully initialized - it's explained in detail here - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think passing `this` to another method inside the constructor might be dangerous. Following page has very good explanation.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

See "Don't publish the "this" reference during construction" section.

If possible, you could delay the `Class2` construction until it is first needed in `Class1`

Answer (score 0):

While this is horribly circular, what you are trying to do should be done as follows:

```
public Class1
{
  public void setClass2(Class2 instance2)
  {
    instance2.setClass1(this);
  }

  public someMethod(String anyString)
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class Class2
{  
  public void setClass1(Class1 instance1)
  {
    instance1.someMethod("the string");
  }
}
```

As I said in my comment in @Chris Cooney's answer:

Publishing this from within the constructor is a bad idea because the reference is assigned before the object is fully initialized - it's explained in detail [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html).